# Catkinized KnowRob - dependency issues

Tags: catkin, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed the new catkinized KnowRob under Hydro, following the [instructions](http://www.knowrob.org/installation/catkin) and the very useful [migration guide](http://knowrob.org/doc/catkin_migration), and everything seems to be working.

However I had a couple of minor issues with dependencies: first, `rosdep` doesn't seem to install dependencies recursively, so some were missed (e.g. see http://answers.ros.org/question/84616/help-understanding-system-and-package-dependencies-with-rosbuild-and-catkin/).

I suggest instead of doing

```
rosdep install --ignore-src knowrob
```

you can use

```
rosdep install --ignore-src --from-paths stacks/
```

Secondly, a few packages are referenced in knowrob_addons but aren't present in the git repo, specifically:

- knowrob_motion_constraints missing knowrob_mesh_reasoning
- semantic_map_to_owl missing semantic_map_to_owl_msgs
- knowrob_cad_models missing iai_cad_tools (for iai_cad_downloader -- which I tried installing, but then it seemed to need access to a private SVN repository)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203030/catkinized-knowrob---dependency-issues/) by [zsaigol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6094/zsaigol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2015-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for reporting these issues! I have addressed them in the wiki and repository:

- Updated documentation with new rosdep command
- knowrob_mesh_reasoning is in the knowrob_dev repository that has been made public recently. I have removed the '-all' installation variant, please use the '-dev' variant to get the complete set of KnowRob repositories.
- The dependency on semantic_map_to_owl_msgs was outdated and has been removed.
- The CAD model downloader erroneously referred to the internal URL of the repository and has been changed to use the public one by default.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1